# rspec + capybara: expect(page) and page.within() cannot see loaded page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm using rspec 3.4.3 and capybara 2.7 in a feature-spec.

when I run this test:

```
 visit course_path( @course )
 expect(page).to have_content('short_title')
```

it turns red:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('short_title')
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find xpath "/html"
```

when I change the test to

```
 visit course_path( @course )
 within('body') do
   expect(page).to have_content('short_title')
 end
```

the test turns green, but as Thomas noted below, this is only because `within` is not doing any work.

when I use

```
 visit course_path( @course )
 page.within('body') do
   expect(page).to have_content('short_title')
 end
```

it turns red again with

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "body"
```

If I output page.html just after the visit  I can see
that the page is acutally there, has valid html and of course
contains a body and the text. everything is visible, no 
fancyfull javascript or css at all.

what is happening here?

Comment: Is the document badly malformed? Have you tried validating it?

Comment: it's possible, due to include ordering. that you're not actually calling Capybaras `within` there, and are instead just creating the RSpec `be_within` matcher (which is aliased as `within`), which ignores the block passed to it, so you're not actually running the expectation.  You can verify that by calling `page.within` instead of just `within`

Comment: show the html that is on the page that contains the expected text? Is the content actually visible? By default Capybara only finds visible elements and contents